# How many anagrams with a specific subword?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find the number of anagrams of "ACKNOWLEDGEMENT" (15 characters) that contain the subword "EDGE".

I know the total number of anagrams is $\frac{15!}{3! \cdot 2!}$. I'm not sure of what to do after this. I know this is an overcount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you understand that the number of anagrams you have correctly given has the division by $3!\cdot 2!$ because of the $3$ E's and $2$ N's in the available letter pool.

To get the number of full anagrams containing "EDGE", you can simply regard $\fbox{EDGE}$ as a single "letter" that you anagram with the other $11$ items in the letter pool. Then you have $12$ items to permute with only the $2$ copies of N to adjust for, using the same calculation as you already exhibited.

Comment: I'm getting $\frac{12!}{2!}$. Did I do it right?

Comment: Yep, looks like you picked it up as intended.

Comment: Would this method work even if the subword isn't already contiguous in the original? For example, if I used the subword "GWE"?

Comment: Provided you take account of what the remaining duplications are, yes. So for a more direct example, arrangements which contain the word "LEEK" would have the same answer. Anagrams containing "WEAN" would too, but the remaining duplication there is now $2$ E's. Anagrams containing "KNEE" have no duplicates in the pool of single letters.

Comment: Cautionary note - this can run into complications if you can make multiple versions of the target included sequence at the same time. So doing the same calculation for included "ENE", for example, needs to account for the fact that anagrams containing "ENENE" will be counted twice in the above technique.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways EDGE can be the first $4$ letters is $1$. The number of ways the remaining letters can be arranged is then $\frac{11!}{2!}.$

The number of ways EDGE can be the $2nd$ to $5th$ letters is $1$. The number of ways the remaining letters can be arranged is then $\frac{11!}{2!}.$

...

So the answer is $\frac{11!}{2!} \times 12.$